# Why i"m having this error: (node:16040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, discord.js

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const riotapi = require('../botconfig.json')

const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const querystring = require('querystring');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
        const champ = args[0]

```
    const Curl = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.11.1/data/pt_BR/champion/${champ}.json`
    const imgUrl = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.11.1/img/champion/${champ}.png`

    console.log(Curl)

    message.channel.send("Procurando pelo campeão: " + champ).then(message => message.delete({timeout: 1000}))

    fetch(Curl)
        .then(res => res.json())    
        .then(champS => {
            let champEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${champ}`)
            .setDescription(`${champS.data.champ.title}`)
            .addField("Classe", `${champS.data.champ.tags}`)
            .addField("Dicas para aprimorar as fights!", `${champS.data.champ.enemytips}`)
            .addField("Dicas para ajudar o time!", `${champS.data.champ.allytips}`)
            .addField("Passiva", `${champS.data.champ.passive.description}`)
            .setThumbnail(imgUrl)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setFooter("Grandmaster, by: IgorDuca")

            message.channel.send(champEmbed)
        })
}
```

Comment: Because `champS.data.champ` is undefined. Please check the response from `Curl`

Comment: It's because I'm trying to take the proprieties of the champion using it name, in this case, the args[0]

Answer (score 0):

Try `embed.setTitle` or visit this website for define it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined

Comment: The error isn't in the embed, it is in the request, because, when I try to use champS.data.Yasuo.id it works and get the id of the champion Yasuo, but when I use championS.data.champion.id it doens't work, because it can get the propriety of id, OBS(champ = args[0])